# how to not send request if inputs are empty in ionic

Tags: javascript, json, http, ionic-framework

i have an $http request.when i press the button,the request is fired.but i want to block the request if the form's inputs are empty.in the inputs i tried with Required.but it didn't work

```js
$scope.submit=function()
{

var loginServiceUrl = 'https://www.yabiladi.com/newsapi/login.json';
var loginServiceData = {
    user: $scope.username,
    password: $scope.password
}

$http.post(loginServiceUrl, loginServiceData).
    then(function (res){
        $scope.drapeau=0;
        console.log(res);
        $scope.user=res.config.data.user;
        
    }).catch(function(response){
            //rien   
})
                
}
```

```html
  <div ng-if="flag==2" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<div ng-show="drapeau">
        <label for="field1"><span>Username:</span>    <div class="loginform"><input type="text"  class="input-field" name="field1" value="" ng-model="username"  /></div></label>
           <label for="field2"><span>Password:</span><div  class="loginform"><input type="password" class="input-field" name="field2" value="" ng-model="password" /></div></label>
         <div class="boutonlogin">
            <button class="button  button-energized button-small" ng-click="submit()" style="width:80px">Login</button>
         </div>
            <label>
            <b><center>if you don't have an account,you can signup</center></b>
            </label>
             <div class="boutonlogin">
             <button class="button  button-energized button-small" ng-href="#/signup/{{flag}}" style="width:80px" ng-click="modal.hide()">Signup</button>

             </div>
 
  </div>
            <div ng-hide="drapeau">
user connected :    {{user}}
 </div>
  </div>
```

in the button there's that submit function.so it will send the request anyway.i want the request to be sent only if the user enters his login and password or disable the button if the inputs are empty

thank you for the  help

Comment: if(loginServiceData.user!=null && loginServiceData.user!=undefined && loginServiceData.password!=null && loginServiceData.password!=undefined){ //$http 
}else{ alert("Please Enter Username & and password");}

Comment: @KalaiselvanA seems pretty simple.though i didn't think about it.anyway thank you.it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//check null and call $http

```
if(loginServiceData.user!=null && loginServiceData.password!=null){
// here you can use your $http call
//$http.post()

}else{
     alert("Please Enter Username && Password");
}
```